# Quaternion to Euler angles conversion regarding rotation sequence

Tags: c++, rotation, quaternions, euler-angles

This is what I have:

- I have a `Vector3D` class that represents a vector or a point in 3D space.
- I have a `Quaternion` class that performs calculus on quaternions, and I can create a rotation unit quaternion from the Angle-Axis representation using a static method `Quaternion::fromAngleAxisRotation(double angle, Vector3D axis)`.
- I have a `EulerAngles` class with alpha, beta, gamma angles, and in constructor I must specify the rotation sequence, that can be one of canonical 12 (XZX, YXZ, ZYX ecc). As private member I have an array of three elements `Vector3D` that specifies rotation sequence axis. I.e. for ZYX rotation I have `axes[0] = Vector3D(1,0,0); axes[1] = Vector3D(0,1,0); axes[2] = Vector3D(0,0,1);`. For XZX rotation sequence I have `axes[0] = Vector3D(1,0,0); axes[1] = Vector3D(0,0,1); axes[2] = Vector3D(1,0,0);` and so on.
- The class `EulerAngles` has a method `getQuaternion()`. This allows to calculate the corresponding quaternion having three rotation angles and the rotation sequence. In order to work, the method creates three ordered `Quaternion` instances using the `Quaternion::fromAngleAxisRotation` static method to find quaternion for single rotation angles and then it multiplies them. This allows me to have a single method that calculates rotation unit quaternion in all twelve rotation sequences.

  `Quaternion qa = Quaternion::fromAngleAxisRotation(alpha, axes[0]);
  Quaternion qb = Quaternion::fromAngleAxisRotation(beta, axes[1]);
  Quaternion qg = Quaternion::fromAngleAxisRotation(gamma, axes[2]);
  return qa * qb * qg;`

And this is what I want:

I have a `Quaternion` instance. I want to create in `EulerAngles` class a method `EulerAngles::setFromQuaternion(Quaternion q)` that allows me to take the quaternion (normalized etc.) and create three angles from it, taking into account the same rotation sequence stored in `axes` array.

Using some math I can take into account every single rotation sequence combination and threat them separately in order to find angles. But I'd like to create a unique method as I do in `EulerAngles::getQuaternion()`.

Is there a way to decompose a unit quaternion into angles giving rotation sequence as input, or I must create twelve different methods in order to find them?

Vector3D.h

```
#ifndef GEOMETRY_VECTOR3D_H_
#define GEOMETRY_VECTOR3D_H_

#include <vector>
#include <ostream>

namespace Geometry {

class Vector3D {
public:

    static const Vector3D Zero;
    static const Vector3D One;
    static const Vector3D UnitX;
    static const Vector3D UnitY;
    static const Vector3D UnitZ;

public:
    Vector3D();
    Vector3D(const double &x, const double &y, const double &z);
    Vector3D(const Vector3D &point);
    virtual ~Vector3D();

    void setX(const double &x);
    void setY(const double &y);
    void setZ(const double &z);
    void set(const double &x, const double &y, const double &z);
    double getX() const;
    double getY() const;
    double getZ() const;
    void get(double *x, double *y, double *z) const;
    void normalize();
    bool isZero() const;
    double getDistanceTo(const Vector3D &point) const;
    double getModule() const;
    double getSquaredModule() const;

    static Vector3D getNormal(const Vector3D &p1, const Vector3D &p2, const Vector3D &p3);

    Vector3D& operator+=(const Vector3D &point);
    Vector3D& operator-=(const Vector3D &point);
    Vector3D& operator*=(const double &value);
    const Vector3D operator+(const Vector3D &point) const;
    const Vector3D operator-(const Vector3D &point) const;
    const Vector3D operator*(const double &value) const;

private:

    double m_x;
    double m_y;
    double m_z;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Geometry::Vector3D &point);

/** A useful typedef for a vector of points. */
typedef std::vector<Vector3D> Vector3DVector;

} // namespace Geometry

#endif // !GEOMETRY_VECTOR3D_H_
```

Vector3D.cpp

```
#include "Geometry/Vector3D.h"
#include <cmath>

namespace Geometry {

const Vector3D Vector3D::Zero  = Vector3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
const Vector3D Vector3D::One   = Vector3D(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
const Vector3D Vector3D::UnitX = Vector3D(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
const Vector3D Vector3D::UnitY = Vector3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
const Vector3D Vector3D::UnitZ = Vector3D(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

Vector3D::Vector3D() {
    m_x = 0.0;
    m_y = 0.0;
    m_z = 0.0;
}

Vector3D::Vector3D(const double &x, const double &y, const double &z) {
    set(x, y, z);
}

Vector3D::Vector3D(const Vector3D &point) {
    m_x = point.m_x;
    m_y = point.m_y;
    m_z = point.m_z;
}

Vector3D::~Vector3D() {

}

void Vector3D::setX(const double &x) {
    m_x = x;
}

void Vector3D::setY(const double &y) {
    m_y = y;
}

void Vector3D::setZ(const double &z) {
    m_z = z;
}

void Vector3D::set(const double &x, const double &y, const double &z) {
    m_x = x;
    m_y = y;
    m_z = z;
}

double Vector3D::getX() const {
    return m_x;
}

double Vector3D::getY() const {
    return m_y;
}

double Vector3D::getZ() const {
    return m_z;
}

void Vector3D::get(double *x, double *y, double *z) const {
    *x = m_x;
    *y = m_y;
    *z = m_z;
}

void Vector3D::normalize() {
    const double r = sqrt(m_x * m_x + m_y * m_y + m_z * m_z);
    if (r == 0) return;
    m_x /= r;
    m_y /= r;
    m_z /= r;
}

bool Vector3D::isZero() const {
    if (m_x == 0.0 && m_y == 0.0 && m_z == 0.0) return true;
    return false;
}

double Vector3D::getDistanceTo(const Vector3D &point) const {
    const double dx = m_x - point.m_x;
    const double dy = m_y - point.m_y;
    const double dz = m_z - point.m_z;
    const double r  = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
    return r;
}

double Vector3D::getModule() const {
    return sqrt(getSquaredModule());
}

double Vector3D::getSquaredModule() const {
    return m_x * m_x + m_y * m_y + m_z * m_z;
}

Vector3D& Vector3D::operator+=(const Vector3D &point) {
    m_x += point.m_x;
    m_y += point.m_y;
    m_z += point.m_z;
    return *this;
}

Vector3D& Vector3D::operator-=(const Vector3D &point) {
    m_x -= point.m_x;
    m_y -= point.m_y;
    m_z -= point.m_z;
    return *this;
}

Vector3D& Vector3D::operator*=(const double &value) {
    m_x *= value;
    m_y *= value;
    m_z *= value;
    return *this;
}

const Vector3D Vector3D::operator+(const Vector3D &point) const {
    return Vector3D(*this) += point;
}

const Vector3D Vector3D::operator-(const Vector3D &point) const {
    return Vector3D(*this) -= point;
}

const Vector3D Vector3D::operator*(const double &value) const {
    return Vector3D(*this) *= value;
}

Vector3D Vector3D::getNormal(const Vector3D &p1, const Vector3D &p2, const Vector3D &p3) {
    return Vector3D(
            (p2.getY() - p1.getY()) * (p3.getZ() - p1.getZ()) - (p3.getY() - p1.getY()) * (p2.getZ() - p1.getZ()),
            (p2.getZ() - p1.getZ()) * (p3.getX() - p1.getX()) - (p3.getZ() - p1.getZ()) * (p2.getX() - p1.getX()),
            (p2.getX() - p1.getX()) * (p3.getY() - p1.getY()) - (p3.getX() - p1.getX()) * (p2.getY() - p1.getY())
            );
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Vector3D &point) {
    os << "(" << point.getX() << ", " << point.getY() << ", " << point.getZ() << ")";
    return os;
}

} // namespace Geometry
```

Quaternion.h

```
#ifndef GEOMETRY_QUATERION_H_
#define GEOMETRY_QUATERION_H_

#include "Geometry/Vector3D.h"

namespace Geometry {

class Quaternion {
public:

    static Quaternion fromAngleAxisRotation(const double &angle, const double &x, const double &y, const double &z);
    static Quaternion fromAngleAxisRotation(const double &angle, const Vector3D &p);
    static Quaternion slerp(const Quaternion &q1, const Quaternion &q2, const double &t, const bool &normalize = true);

public:

    Quaternion();
    explicit Quaternion(const double &q0);
    Quaternion(const double &q0, const double &q1, const double &q2, const double &q3);
    Quaternion(const Quaternion &rhs);
    virtual ~Quaternion();
    void setQ0(const double &q0);
    void setQ1(const double &q1);
    void setQ2(const double &q2);
    void setQ3(const double &q3);
    void setQ(const size_t &position, const double &q);
    void set(const double &q0, const double &q1, const double &q2, const double &q3);
    double getQ0() const;
    double getQ1() const;
    double getQ2() const;
    double getQ3() const;
    double getQ(const size_t &position) const;
    Quaternion getReal() const;
    Quaternion getUnreal() const;
    Quaternion getConjugate() const;
    Quaternion getInverse() const;
    Quaternion getNormalized() const;
    double dot(const Quaternion &rhs) const;
    double getAbs() const;
    double getNorm() const;
    void conjugate();
    void invert();
    void normalize();

public:

    Quaternion& operator  = (const Quaternion           &rhs);
    Quaternion& operator  = (const double               &rhs);
    Quaternion& operator += (const Quaternion           &rhs);
    Quaternion& operator += (const double               &rhs);
    Quaternion& operator -= (const Quaternion           &rhs);
    Quaternion& operator -= (const double               &rhs);
    Quaternion& operator *= (const Quaternion           &rhs);
    Quaternion& operator *= (const double               &rhs);
    Quaternion& operator /= (const Quaternion           &rhs);
    Quaternion& operator /= (const double               &rhs);

private:

    void checkIndex(const size_t &index) const;

private:

    double q[4];

};

} // namespace Geometry

Geometry::Quaternion operator + (const Geometry::Quaternion &lhs, const Geometry::Quaternion &rhs);
Geometry::Quaternion operator + (const Geometry::Quaternion &lhs, const double                    &rhs);
Geometry::Quaternion operator + (const double                    &lhs, const Geometry::Quaternion &rhs);
Geometry::Quaternion operator - (const Geometry::Quaternion &lhs, const Geometry::Quaternion &rhs);
Geometry::Quaternion operator - (const Geometry::Quaternion &lhs, const double                    &rhs);
Geometry::Quaternion operator - (const double                    &lhs, const Geometry::Quaternion &rhs);
Geometry::Quaternion operator * (const Geometry::Quaternion &lhs, const Geometry::Quaternion &rhs);
Geometry::Quaternion operator * (const Geometry::Quaternion &lhs, const double                    &rhs);
Geometry::Quaternion operator * (const double                    &lhs, const Geometry::Quaternion &rhs);
Geometry::Quaternion operator / (const Geometry::Quaternion &lhs, const Geometry::Quaternion &rhs);
Geometry::Quaternion operator / (const Geometry::Quaternion &lhs, const double                    &rhs);
Geometry::Quaternion operator / (const double                    &lhs, const Geometry::Quaternion &rhs);


#endif // !GEOMETRY_QUATERION_H_
```

Quaternion.cpp

```
#include "Geometry/Quaternion.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>

namespace Geometry {

using std::out_of_range;
using std::underflow_error;
using std::stringstream;

Quaternion Quaternion::fromAngleAxisRotation(const double &angle, const double &x, const double &y, const double &z) {
    return fromAngleAxisRotation(angle, Vector3D(x, y, z));
}

/**
 * A central rotation in space can be defined as a rotation of specifid amount
 * @f$\theta@f$ and a rotation axis, defined as vector @f$\left(x, y, z
 * \right)@f$. This method allows to build the quaternion relative to that
 * rotation.
 *
 * @param[in] angle Rotation angle (radians).
 * @param[in] p     Rotation axis.
 *
 * @return Quaternion related to this rotation.
 *
 * @throw std::underflow_error if vector is null.
 */
Quaternion Quaternion::fromAngleAxisRotation(const double &angle, const Vector3D &p) {
    const double halfAngleSin = sin(angle * 0.5);
    Vector3D np = p;
    np.normalize();
    return Quaternion(cos(angle * 0.5), np.getX() * halfAngleSin, np.getY() * halfAngleSin, np.getZ() * halfAngleSin);
}

Quaternion Quaternion::slerp(const Quaternion &q1, const Quaternion &q2, const double &t, const bool &normalize) {
    const double dotProduct = q1.dot(q2);
    const double ht = t * 0.5;
    double       theta = acos(dotProduct);
    if (theta < 0.0) theta = -theta;
    const double st = 1.0 / sin(theta);
    const double sut = sin(ht * theta);
    const double sout = sin((1.0 - ht) * theta);
    const double w1 = sout * st;
    const double w2 = sut * st;
    Quaternion res = ((w1 * q1) + (w2 * q2));
    if (true == normalize) {
        res.normalize();
    }
    return res;
}

Quaternion::Quaternion() {
    q[0] = 0.0;
    q[1] = 0.0;
    q[2] = 0.0;
    q[3] = 0.0;
}

Quaternion::Quaternion(const double &q0) {
    q[0] = q0;
    q[1] = 0.0;
    q[2] = 0.0;
    q[3] = 0.0;
}

Quaternion::Quaternion(const double &q0, const double &q1, const double &q2, const double &q3) {
    q[0] = q0;
    q[1] = q1;
    q[2] = q2;
    q[3] = q3;
}

Quaternion::Quaternion(const Quaternion &rhs) {
    q[0] = rhs.q[0];
    q[1] = rhs.q[1];
    q[2] = rhs.q[2];
    q[3] = rhs.q[3];
}

Quaternion::~Quaternion() {

}

void Quaternion::setQ0(const double &q0) {
    q[0] = q0;
}

void Quaternion::setQ1(const double &q1) {
    q[1] = q1;
}

void Quaternion::setQ2(const double &q2) {
    q[2] = q2;
}

void Quaternion::setQ3(const double &q3) {
    q[3] = q3;
}

void Quaternion::setQ(const size_t &index, const double &q) {
    checkIndex(index);
    this->q[index] = q;
}

void Quaternion::set(const double &q0, const double &q1, const double &q2, const double &q3) {
    q[0] = q0;
    q[1] = q1;
    q[2] = q2;
    q[3] = q3;
}

double Quaternion::getQ0() const {
    return q[0];
}

double Quaternion::getQ1() const {
    return q[1];
}

double Quaternion::getQ2() const {
    return q[2];
}

double Quaternion::getQ3() const {
    return q[3];
}

double Quaternion::getQ(const size_t &index) const {
    checkIndex(index);
    return q[index];
}

Quaternion Quaternion::getReal() const {
    return Quaternion(q[0], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

Quaternion Quaternion::getUnreal() const {
    return Quaternion(0.0, q[1], q[2], q[3]);
}

Quaternion Quaternion::getConjugate() const {
    return Quaternion(q[0], -q[1], -q[2], -q[3]);
}

Quaternion Quaternion::getInverse() const {
    Quaternion quat(*this);
    quat.invert();
    return quat;
}

Quaternion Quaternion::getNormalized() const {
    Quaternion quat(*this);
    quat.normalize();
    return quat;
}

double Quaternion::dot(const Quaternion &rhs) const {
    return q[0] * rhs.q[0] + q[1] * rhs.q[1] + q[2] * rhs.q[2] + q[3] * rhs.q[3];
}

double Quaternion::getAbs() const {
    return sqrt(getNorm());
}

double Quaternion::getNorm() const {
    return q[0] * q[0] + q[1] * q[1] + q[2] * q[2] + q[3] * q[3];
}

void Quaternion::conjugate() {
    q[1] = -q[1];
    q[2] = -q[2];
    q[3] = -q[3];
}

void Quaternion::invert() {
    const double denominator = getNorm();
    if (denominator == 0.0) throw underflow_error("QUATERNION_ZERO_DENOMINATOR");
    const double invDen = 1.0 / denominator;
    q[0] *= invDen;
    q[1] *= invDen;
    q[2] *= invDen;
    q[3] *= invDen;;
    q[1]  = -q[1];
    q[2]  = -q[2];
    q[3]  = -q[3];
}

void Quaternion::normalize() {
    const double denominator = getAbs();
    if (denominator == 0.0) throw underflow_error("QUATERNION_ZERO_DENOMINATOR");
    const double invDen = 1.0 / denominator;
    q[0] *= invDen;
    q[1] *= invDen;
    q[2] *= invDen;
    q[3] *= invDen;
}

Quaternion& Quaternion::operator = (const Quaternion &rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
        q[0] = rhs.q[0];
        q[1] = rhs.q[1];
        q[2] = rhs.q[2];
        q[3] = rhs.q[3];
    }
    return *this;
}

Quaternion& Quaternion::operator = (const double &rhs) {
    q[0] = rhs;
    q[1] = 0.0;
    q[2] = 0.0;
    q[3] = 0.0;
    return *this;
}

Quaternion& Quaternion::operator += (const Quaternion &rhs) {
    q[0] += rhs.q[0];
    q[1] += rhs.q[1];
    q[2] += rhs.q[2];
    q[3] += rhs.q[3];
    return *this;
}

Quaternion& Quaternion::operator += (const double &rhs) {
    q[0] += rhs;
    return *this;
}

Quaternion& Quaternion::operator -= (const Quaternion &rhs) {
    q[0] -= rhs.q[0];
    q[1] -= rhs.q[1];
    q[2] -= rhs.q[2];
    q[3] -= rhs.q[3];
    return *this;
}

Quaternion& Quaternion::operator -= (const double &rhs) {
    q[0] -= rhs;
    return *this;
}

Quaternion& Quaternion::operator *= (const Quaternion &rhs) {
    const double q0 = q[0] * rhs.q[0] - q[1] * rhs.q[1] - q[2] * rhs.q[2] - q[3] * rhs.q[3];
    const double q1 = q[1] * rhs.q[0] + q[0] * rhs.q[1] - q[3] * rhs.q[2] + q[2] * rhs.q[3];
    const double q2 = q[2] * rhs.q[0] + q[3] * rhs.q[1] + q[0] * rhs.q[2] - q[1] * rhs.q[3];
    const double q3 = q[3] * rhs.q[0] - q[2] * rhs.q[1] + q[1] * rhs.q[2] + q[0] * rhs.q[3];
    set(q0, q1, q2, q3);
    return *this;
}

Quaternion& Quaternion::operator *= (const double &rhs) {
    q[0] *= rhs;
    q[1] *= rhs;
    q[2] *= rhs;
    q[3] *= rhs;
    return *this;
}

Quaternion& Quaternion::operator /= (const Quaternion &rhs) {
    const double denominator = rhs.getNorm();
    if (denominator == 0.0) throw underflow_error("QUATERNION_ZERO_DENOMINATOR");
    const double invDen = 1.0 / denominator;
    const double q0 = (q[0] * rhs.q[0] + q[1] * rhs.q[1] + q[2] * rhs.q[2] + q[3] * rhs.q[3]) * invDen;
    const double q1 = (q[1] * rhs.q[0] - q[0] * rhs.q[1] - q[3] * rhs.q[2] + q[2] * rhs.q[3]) * invDen;
    const double q2 = (q[2] * rhs.q[0] + q[3] * rhs.q[1] - q[0] * rhs.q[2] - q[1] * rhs.q[3]) * invDen;
    const double q3 = (q[3] * rhs.q[0] - q[2] * rhs.q[1] + q[1] * rhs.q[2] - q[0] * rhs.q[3]) * invDen;
    set(q0, q1, q2, q3);
    return *this;
}

Quaternion& Quaternion::operator /= (const double &rhs) {
    if (rhs == 0.0) throw underflow_error("QUATERNION_ZERO_DENOMINATOR");
    const double invRhs = 1.0 / rhs;
    q[0] *= invRhs;
    q[1] *= invRhs;
    q[2] *= invRhs;
    q[3] *= invRhs;
    return *this;
}

void Quaternion::checkIndex(const size_t &index) const {
    if (index > 3) {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << QUATERNION_OUT_OF_RANGE << " " << index;
        throw out_of_range(ss.str());
    }
}

} // namespace Geometry

Geometry::Quaternion operator + (const Geometry::Quaternion &lhs, const Geometry::Quaternion &rhs) {
    Geometry::Quaternion res(lhs);
    res += rhs;
    return res;
}

Geometry::Quaternion operator + (const Geometry::Quaternion &lhs, const double &rhs) {
    Geometry::Quaternion res(lhs);
    res += rhs;
    return res;
}

Geometry::Quaternion operator + (const double &lhs, const Geometry::Quaternion &rhs) {
    return rhs + lhs;
}

Geometry::Quaternion operator - (const Geometry::Quaternion &lhs, const Geometry::Quaternion &rhs) {
    Geometry::Quaternion res(lhs);
    res -= rhs;
    return res;
}

Geometry::Quaternion operator - (const Geometry::Quaternion &lhs, const double &rhs) {
    Geometry::Quaternion res(lhs);
    res -= rhs;
    return res;
}

Geometry::Quaternion operator - (const double &lhs, const Geometry::Quaternion &rhs) {
    return rhs - lhs;
}

Geometry::Quaternion operator * (const Geometry::Quaternion &lhs, const Geometry::Quaternion &rhs) {
    Geometry::Quaternion res(lhs);
    res *= rhs;
    return res;
}

Geometry::Quaternion operator * (const Geometry::Quaternion &lhs, const double &rhs) {
    Geometry::Quaternion res(lhs);
    res *= rhs;
    return res;
}

Geometry::Quaternion operator * (const double &lhs, const Geometry::Quaternion &rhs) {
    return rhs * lhs;
}

Geometry::Quaternion operator / (const Geometry::Quaternion &lhs, const Geometry::Quaternion &rhs) {
    Geometry::Quaternion res(lhs);
    res /= rhs;
    return res;
}

Geometry::Quaternion operator / (const Geometry::Quaternion &lhs, const double &rhs) {
    Geometry::Quaternion res(lhs);
    res /= rhs;
    return res;
}

Geometry::Quaternion operator / (const double &lhs, const Geometry::Quaternion &rhs) {
    return rhs / lhs;
}
```

EulerAngles.h

```
#ifndef GEOMETRY_EULERANGLES_H_
#define GEOMETRY_EULERANGLES_H_

#include "Geometry/Quaternion.h"
#include "Geometry/Vector3D.h"

namespace Geometry {

class EulerAngles {
public:

    enum RotationSequence {
        XZX,
        XYX,
        YXY,
        YZY,
        ZYZ,
        ZXZ,
        XZY,
        XYZ,
        YXZ,
        YZX,
        ZYX,
        ZXY
    };

public:
    EulerAngles(const RotationSequence &sequence = ZYX);
    EulerAngles(const double &alpha, const double &beta, const double &gamma, const RotationSequence &sequence = ZYX);
    EulerAngles(const EulerAngles &rhs);
    virtual ~EulerAngles();
    void setAlpha(const double &alpha);
    void setBeta(const double &beta);
    void setGamma(const double &gamma);
    void set(const double &alpha, const double &beta, const double &gamma);
    /* This is the method that I want to implement */
    void setFromQuaternion(const Quaternion &quat);
    void rotate(const EulerAngles &angles);
    void rotate(const double &alpha, const double &beta, const double &gamma);
    double getAlpha() const;
    double getBeta() const;
    double getGamma() const;
    Quaternion getQuaternion() const;
    RotationSequence getRotationSequence() const;
    EulerAngles getRotatedAngles(const double &alpha, const double &beta, const double &gamma) const;
    EulerAngles getRotatedAngles(const EulerAngles &angles) const;

private:

    void setRotationSequenceAxis(const RotationSequence &sequence);

private:

    RotationSequence rotationSequence;
    Vector3D axes[3];
    double alpha;
    double beta;
    double gamma;
};

} // namespace Geometry

#endif // !GEOMETRY_EULERANGLES_H_
```

EulerAngles.cpp

```
#include "Geometry/EulerAngles.h"

namespace Geometry {

EulerAngles::EulerAngles(const RotationSequence &sequence) {
    rotationSequence = sequence;
    alpha = 0.0;
    beta = 0.0;
    gamma = 0.0;
    setRotationSequenceAxis(sequence);
}

EulerAngles::EulerAngles(const double &alpha, const double &beta, const double &gamma, const RotationSequence &sequence) {
    rotationSequence = sequence;
    this->alpha = alpha;
    this->beta = beta;
    this->gamma = gamma;
    setRotationSequenceAxis(sequence);
}

EulerAngles::EulerAngles(const EulerAngles &rhs) {
    rotationSequence = rhs.rotationSequence;
    alpha = rhs.alpha;
    beta = rhs.beta;
    gamma = rhs.gamma;
    setRotationSequenceAxis(rotationSequence);
}

EulerAngles::~EulerAngles() {

}

void EulerAngles::setAlpha(const double &alpha) {
    this->alpha = alpha;
}

void EulerAngles::setBeta(const double &beta) {
    this->beta = beta;
}

void EulerAngles::setGamma(const double &gamma) {
    this->gamma = gamma;
}

void EulerAngles::set(const double &alpha, const double &beta, const double &gamma) {
    this->alpha = alpha;
    this->beta = beta;
    this->gamma = gamma;
}

/**
 * Given a quaternion, calculate rotation angles using the internally defined axis
 * rotation sequence.
 *
 * @param[in] quat Quaternion.
 */
void EulerAngles::setFromQuaternion(const Quaternion &quat) {
    const Quaternion q = quat.getNormalized();
    /*************************************************************
     * This is where I want to calculate Euler angles having the *
     * quaternion as input and the rotation sequence. of the     *
     * instance of this class                                    *
     *************************************************************/
     #error This is where I want to set angles from quat and stored rotation sequence.
}

void EulerAngles::rotate(const double &alpha, const double &beta, const double &gamma) {
    EulerAngles angles(alpha, beta, gamma, rotationSequence);
    rotate(angles);
}

/**
 * Euler angles represent a rotation body in 3D space. With this method
 * is possibile to rotate the body by specified amount. In this case
 * this orientation is rotated using the rotation sequence specified into
 * the argument.
 *
 * @param[in] angles Rotation amount.
 */
void EulerAngles::rotate(const EulerAngles &angles) {
    const Quaternion q1 = getQuaternion();
    const Quaternion q2 = angles.getQuaternion();
    const Quaternion q3(q1 * q2);
    setFromQuaternion(q3);
}

double EulerAngles::getAlpha() const {
    return alpha;
}

double EulerAngles::getBeta() const {
    return beta;
}

double EulerAngles::getGamma() const {
    return gamma;
}

Quaternion EulerAngles::getQuaternion() const {
    const Quaternion qAlpha = Quaternion::fromAngleAxisRotation(alpha, axes[0]);
    const Quaternion qBeta  = Quaternion::fromAngleAxisRotation(beta , axes[1]);
    const Quaternion qGamma = Quaternion::fromAngleAxisRotation(gamma, axes[2]);
    return (qAlpha * qBeta) * qGamma;
}

EulerAngles::RotationSequence EulerAngles::getRotationSequence() const {
    return rotationSequence;
}

void EulerAngles::setRotationSequenceAxis(const RotationSequence &sequence) {
    switch (sequence) {
    case XZX : {
        axes[0] = Vector3D::UnitX;
        axes[1] = Vector3D::UnitZ;
        axes[2] = Vector3D::UnitX;
    } break;
    case XYX : {
        axes[0] = Vector3D::UnitX;
        axes[1] = Vector3D::UnitY;
        axes[2] = Vector3D::UnitX;
    } break;
    case YXY : {
        axes[0] = Vector3D::UnitY;
        axes[1] = Vector3D::UnitX;
        axes[2] = Vector3D::UnitY;
    } break;
    case YZY : {
        axes[0] = Vector3D::UnitY;
        axes[1] = Vector3D::UnitZ;
        axes[2] = Vector3D::UnitY;
    } break;
    case ZYZ : {
        axes[0] = Vector3D::UnitZ;
        axes[1] = Vector3D::UnitY;
        axes[2] = Vector3D::UnitZ;
    } break;
    case ZXZ : {
        axes[0] = Vector3D::UnitZ;
        axes[1] = Vector3D::UnitX;
        axes[2] = Vector3D::UnitZ;
    } break;
    case XZY : {
        axes[0] = Vector3D::UnitX;
        axes[1] = Vector3D::UnitZ;
        axes[2] = Vector3D::UnitY;
    } break;
    case XYZ : {
        axes[0] = Vector3D::UnitX;
        axes[1] = Vector3D::UnitY;
        axes[2] = Vector3D::UnitZ;
    } break;
    case YXZ : {
        axes[0] = Vector3D::UnitY;
        axes[1] = Vector3D::UnitX;
        axes[2] = Vector3D::UnitZ;
    } break;
    case YZX : {
        axes[0] = Vector3D::UnitY;
        axes[1] = Vector3D::UnitZ;
        axes[2] = Vector3D::UnitX;
    } break;
    case ZYX : {
        axes[0] = Vector3D::UnitZ;
        axes[1] = Vector3D::UnitY;
        axes[2] = Vector3D::UnitX;
    } break;
    case ZXY : {
        axes[0] = Vector3D::UnitZ;
        axes[1] = Vector3D::UnitX;
        axes[2] = Vector3D::UnitY;
    } break;
    }
}

} // namespace Geometry
```